# How to always transition to the initial view of a tab in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this scenario:

[image]

Both view 1 and view 2 transitions to final view.

Now, here comes the problem.

When I transition from view 1 to final view, then I tap item 2, it transitions to view 2. But then I tap item 1, it transitions to final view. This is because view 1 was transitioned to final view awhile ago.

So, is there anyway that I could always show view 1 when item1 is tapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you should try it:

```
class FinalViewController:UIViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
   }

   func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController,didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        let tabBarIndex = tabBarController.selectedIndex
        if tabBarIndex == 0 {
            _ =   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }else{
    //whatever

}
   }
}
```

Comment: oh no prob buddy !!